# Set of Matrices Over Finite Field Whose Pairwise Differences are Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank

Given the full matrix ring over a finite field, $M := M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for prime $q$ and integer $n$, what can one say about subsets $S$ of $M$ satisfying the condition that:

$A,B \in S$ implies $A - B$ is invertible unless $A = B$ (n.b. I'm not making any assumptions on the invertibility of elements of $S$ themselves).

Is it possible to construct, or show the existence of, relatively large subsets satisfying this condition? I'm particularly interested in the case where $q$ scales asymptotically and $n$ is a fixed, small constant, and by large subsets I'm attempting to construct $S$ with $\vert S \vert \approx O(q^n)$, but suspect this is infeasible.

As for my own attempts, I thought initially that given the collection of all subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ of dimension $n-1$, one ought to be able to choose one element from each subspace so that the difference of any two elements is full rank, and thus invertible. This would lead to a set $S$ of size ${n \choose n-1}_q = 1+ \dots + q^{n-1}$, but I am unable to prove that this is either achievable or impossible.

Asymptotically, I've only been able to come up with obvious naive sets of size $q$, but playing around with small cases suggests that larger sets are possible in some cases, just they do not exhibit an obvious pattern (at least not obvious to me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The largest possible such a set $S$ has exactly $q^n$ elements:

- The extension field $L=\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ has $q^n$ elements and can be embedded into $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{F}_q)$ as a subring. The difference between any two distinct elements of $L$ then has an inverse in $L$.
- On the other hand, if $|S|\ge q^n+1$ then, by the pigeonhole principle, some two elements of $S$, say $A$ and $B$, will have the same first row. Their difference $A-B$ thus has all zeros on the first row, and cannot be invertible.

---

In small cases it is easy to describe an embedding (there are several). For example, if $n=2$ and $q$ is an odd prime we can find a quadratic non-residue $\epsilon\in\Bbb{F}_q$. Then the collection of matrices of the form
$$
M(a,b)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a& \epsilon b\\ b&a\end{array}\right)
$$
forms a subfield $L=\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$. The determinant $\det M(a,b)=a^2-\epsilon b^2$ vanishes only when $a=b=0$. Furthermore, the difference of two such matrices is of the same form. This is a generalization of the well known way of representing complex numbers by $2\times 2$ real matrices:
$$a+ib\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&-b\\ b&a\end{array}\right),$$
where we use $-1$ as a non-square.

When $n=3$, $p\neq3$ we can similarly use a non-cube $\epsilon$ and matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a&\epsilon c&\epsilon b\\
b&a&\epsilon c\\
c&b&a\end{array}\right).$$

For larger $n$ the method of describing an explicit set of matrices becomes a bit more complicated. If $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of a generator of the extension field, we can use $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear combinations of the powers $A^i$, $i=0,1,2\ldots,n-1$, of the companion matrix $A$ of $m(x)$.

Comment: Nice answer. These also correspond nicely to spreads of $\mathrm{PG}(2n-1,q)$ and are well studied in this context (I feel like I've seen this called a *Kerdock set*, but maybe only when the matrices are skew-symmetric?).

Comment: Another approach for finding these matrices: note that $\Bbb F_{p^k}$ has the structure of a $k$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb F_p$, and that multiplication by elements in $\Bbb F_{p^k}$ is linear.  Once you've chosen some basis for $\Bbb F_{p^k}$ as a $\Bbb F_p$-vector space, it suffices to determine the matrix of the map $x \mapsto ax$ for all elements $a \in \Bbb F_p$.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Am I right in saying this method ought to supply a number of sets $S$ equal to the number choices of finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ e.g. the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$? Or does the uniqueness up to isomorphism mean that some of the sets are/can be the same?

I'm not so familiar with spreads of projective spaces, although I've taken a quick look this morning - does the correspondence relate to the finite fields $L$ as in Jyrki's answer or might this method provide even more sets $S$?

Comment: @Charlie A priori there is no need for the set $S$ to be closed under matrix multiplication (which holds when we construct the set this way). For example, adding an arbitrary constant matrix to all the elements of $S$ won't change your property. Similarly, if $X$ and $Y$ are fixed invertible matrice, multiplying all the elements of $S$ from the left by $X$ and from the right by $Y$ won't change the property as
$$XAY-XBY=X(A-B)Y$$ for all $A,B\in S$ and $A-B$ is invertible iff $X(A-B)Y$ is.

Comment: But, I think that the Skolem-Noether theorem implies the following. If $S$ and $S'$ are two copies of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ inside $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{F}_q)$, then there exists an invertible matrix $X$ such that $S'=XSX^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems I now have a lot of way to choose these sets :)

Comment: @Charlie Pretty sure the finite field method given above will always lead to a Desarguesian spread; in general the classification of spreads is a very open problem. They can be used to construct lots of other cool objects (translation planes in particular, which are an interesting class of projective planes).

Comment: Actually, invoking Skolem-Noether is overkill here. Just fix a generator $g$ for the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$. Its minimal polynomial is then also fixed, meaning that the two matrices representing $g$ are similar. The matrix $X$ giving the related similiarity transformation then obviously also works for powers of $g$, i.e. the whole field.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Somehow I have managed to miss the fact that this area is one of your specialties. Had I known that I would have left this for you to answer. Sorry about hogging the question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No problem at all, I was traveling this weekend so I'm not sure I would have had a chance to write a detailed answer. I was happy to see yours!